# websocket push message programmatically using java code

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, spring-websocket

java 8 Spring 5 mvc Websocket handler.

how do it push websocket message programmatically(using javacode) to the client ?

I followed following example.

http://boraji.com/spring-mvc-5-handling-websocket-message-example

which creates `TextWebsocketHandler`.

```
@Component
public class MyWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

   @Override
   protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
         throws Exception {

      String clientMessage = message.getPayload();

      if (clientMessage.startsWith("Hello") || clientMessage.startsWith("Hi")) {
         session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hello! What can i do for you?"));
      } else {
         session.sendMessage(
               new TextMessage("This is a simple hello world example of using Spring WebSocket."));
      }
   }
}
```

and then pass it to websocket configurere

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@ComponentScan("com.boraji.tutorial.spring.websocket")
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

   @Autowired
   private MyWebSocketHandler myWebSocketHandler;

   @Override
   public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addHandler(myWebSocketHandler, "/socketHandler");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save your `WebSocketSession` somewhere in your code, and then call `sendMessage(TextMessage m)` on it when ever you want to send something back to the client.

For example you can save the WebSocketSession Reference when `OnOpen` method is called in your handler. The reference is passed as a parameter.

But anyways, your code is just doing it at:

```
session.sendMessage(
           new TextMessage("This is a simple hello world example of using Spring WebSocket."));
```

and at

```
session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hello! What can i do for you?"));
```

What do you mean by programmatically? you could for example create a protocol for yourself and how you handle the messages.